# Google identity service Signin Button don't appear without page refresh

Tags: google-signin, google-identity

I got a strange behavior from [Google Identity Service](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/) signin button while implementing it with react. When I first visit the signin page the Google signin button do not appear but one tap window appear. If I refresh the page then both appears. After that if I navigate to other page and come back to signin page button disappear again but one tap window appear.

page first loading
[image]

page after browser refresh
[image]

I used the following code for signin button

```
renderGoogleSignInButton = () => {
return (
  <>
    <div
      id="g_id_onload"
      data-client_id="MY_CLIENT_ID"
      data-auto_prompt="false"
      data-auto_select="true"
      data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
    ></div>
    <div
      className="g_id_signin mt-4 flex justify-center"
      data-type="standard"
      data-size="large"
      data-theme="outline"
      data-text="sign_in_with"
      data-shape="rectangular"
      data-logo_alignment="left"
    ></div>
  </>
)
```

}

and following code for one tap window

```
componentDidMount() {
google.accounts.id.initialize({
  client_id: MY_CLIENT_ID,
  callback: this.handleCredentialResponse,
})
google.accounts.id.prompt()
```

}

I didn't find any clue using google search, not even in the docs.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: For the sign-in button it might be the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/a/70993934/6113915
Don't know about the one-tap problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the One Tap prompt is being displayed as expected, but it was a little unclear. If you're having issues with One Tap, Check out the [`PromptMomentNotification`](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference?hl=en#google.accounts.id.prompt) and `getNotDisplayedReason` values, they should help you to understand the reason why the One Tap prompt may not be displayed. You might also consider [One Tap in an iframe](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/amp/intermediate-iframe) if there's an issue with React being hard to debug.

For the button, if you've not found anything suspicious with pre-rendering, caching or when the div tag containing `g_id_signin` is loaded you might try rendering the button browser side using JS and [renderButton](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference?hl=en#google.accounts.id.renderButton).

Comment: Thanks! HTML didn't work. I used JS renderButton and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

For those who will have this problem in future with react.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props)
window.handleCredentialResponse = this.handleCredentialResponse
this.myRef = React.createRef()
}
componentDidMount() {
if (window.google) {
  window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id:MY_CLIENT_ID
    callback: this.handleCredentialResponse,
  })
  window.google.accounts.id.prompt()
  window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(this.myRef.current, {
    theme: 'outline',
    size: 'large',
  })
 }
}
......
}
```

Comment: Would be nice to have a full example. what to return as view? (also for functional component)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - login button would not appear without a refresh. For me, it was simply a matter of moving the below logic from App.tsx to Login.tsx.

```
useEffect(() => {

    dispatch(setCurrentPage("login"));

    google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
        callback: handleCallbackResponse
    });

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
    const googleLoginDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("googleLoginDiv")!;

    google.accounts.id.renderButton(googleLoginDiv, { 
        type: "standard",
        theme: "outline", 
        size: "large"
    });

}, []);
```