# New google sign in disappears after refreshing page

Tags: html, google-signin, svelte, sveltekit

I followed the guidelines that provided by google to integrate new google sign in. I created HTML using Code generator that [provided by Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/tools/configurator).

Here I have attached the complete code

```
 <svelte:head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Svelte demo app" />
</svelte:head>

<section>
    <div class="h-screen">
        <div
            id="g_id_onload"
            data-client_id="534101779287-bm07dc8v4ln4kulqbql61nsglcku74vg.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            data-context="use"
            data-ux_mode="redirect"
            data-login_uri="http://localhost:5173/auth/callback"
        />
        <div class="bg-red-300 h-80">
            <div
                class="g_id_signin"
                data-type="standard"
                data-shape="rectangular"
                data-theme="outline"
                data-text="signin_with"
                data-size="medium"
                data-logo_alignment="left"
                data-width="180"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

It works fine for the first time render of the page.
[image]

When we are refreshing the page using `Command+R` or by clicking reload icon from the browser, **Sign in button disappears.**
[image]

Comment: You might want to include how you added any JS/scripts if you want more specific answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the Sign In With Google button disappear after I render it the second time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70993933/why-does-the-sign-in-with-google-button-disappear-after-i-render-it-the-second-t)

Comment: @user1844933 While this might be the same or a similar issue, some of the solutions are fairly React-specific. It would be nice to have a canonical solution for Svelte/SvelteKit as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hard reload is server-side rendered when using SvelteKit. The code is probably incompatible with that or the execution order is wrong.

Check the console for errors and move code that has to run on the client to [`onMount`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-onmount). You can also turn off server-side rendering for specific pages using the [`ssr` page option](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#ssr) as a *last resort*.

Comment: There is no console error, for hard reload it's working fine, It's not working in reload

Comment: A hard reload is what you claimed to have done, `Ctrl + R`, as opposed to a client-side load caused by navigation.

Comment: Above code is working command + shift + R (Hard reload) working, command + R (Reload)not working, and when we create the component using Java script working for client side (all the time). Code that I shared on the question created from google html generator not working (Height is zero when we are reloading)

Comment: Then you should obviously look into caching/execution order issues. Also, as I already noted on the question: Show the entirety of the code if you want better answers.

Comment: I added an answer using Javascript code that works now

Answer (score 1):

For now I created component using Javascript, Here I have added the answer.

I declared google as global variable in `app.d.ts`

```
// See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#app
    // for information about these interfaces
    declare global {
        const google: any;
        namespace App {
        }
    }
export {};
```

I created a svelte file to create a svelte component for sign in button

```
let canvas: any; //Created a variable to optain a reference to rendered div element
    <div class="g_id_signin"
bind:this={canvas}/>
```

In onMount

```
onMount(async () => {   
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
                client_id: "534101779287-bm07dc8v4ln4kulqbql61nsglcku74vg.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                ux_mode: "redirect",
                context: "use",
                login_uri: "http://localhost:5173/auth/callback"
            });
            google.accounts.id.renderButton(canvas, {
                width: '220',      
                theme: 'outline',
                size: 'large',
                type: 'standard',
                text: 'signin_with',
                shape: 'rectangular',
                logo_alignment: 'left',
                  
            });

    });
```

This code will work in initial render, Hard reload (Command+shift+R) and Reload (Command+R)